# Отловить команду telegram-ботом от пользователя с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь отловить команду telegram-ботом от пользователя с помощью регулярного выражения. Команды такого вида '/45623456', '/45678909', то есть обратный слэш и восемь цифр. Вот хендлер:

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp="/\d{8}")
def handle_message(message):
    pass
```

Но данный пример ничего разумного не даёт:

```
2017-10-24 09:00:35,845 (util.py:64 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "TypeError occurred, args=("'NoneType' object is not callable",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 58, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Кто практиковал, прошу подсказать, как правильно сделать?

python3.4, telebot

Comment: Я б поправил на `\\d`, но, похоже, дело не в этом: https://ideone.com/8iIYqL

Comment: @Qwertiy не в этом, да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/README.rst) есть пример обработчика с lambda-функцией, с помощью которой можно гибко задавать условия *отлова* сообщений:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
    def echo_all(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
```

Соответственно, вместо `True` нужно подставить необходимое условие.